flutter error unknown userid on domain joined ubuntu
I have an ubuntu 20.04 machine that is domains joined (sssd) to an univention server. When I do
flutter --version

on a domain account, I get
2024/10/12 14:00:49.169098 cmd_run.go:1276: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: aktueller Benutzer kann nicht ermittelt werden: user: unknown userid 2053

2024/10/12 14:00:49.169235 cmd_run.go:1281: WARNING: cannot copy user Xauthority file: aktueller Benutzer kann nicht ermittelt werden: user: unknown userid 2053

Flutter 3.24.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision 2663184aa7 (vor 4 Wochen) • 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500

Engine • revision 36335019a8

Tools • Dart 3.5.3 • DevTools 2.37.3
If I use I local account I don't have this error.
id

uid=2053(hans) gid=5001(Domain Users)...

getent passwd | grep hans

hans:\*:2053:5001:Hans Xxxxxx:/home/hans:/bin/bash

Reinstalling flutter (via snap) doesn't change the situation
I have a different domain joined ubuntu 20.04 machine running flutter 3.5.3. There the error message doesn't show.
sudo chown -R hans:Domain\\ Users \*

doesn't help
If I use I local account I don't have this error.
Reinstalling flutter (via snap) doesn't change the situation
flutter still seems to work.
I run out of ideas.
